# async/await continuation in another process

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

Let's assume we have two processes executing the same code, i.e. both processes have completely the same codebase. The code calls async operation that makes a request over the network to the third process. Is it possible to initiate async operation on process #1 and process the continuation on process #2?

```
public class ResourcesService : IResourcesService
{
    public async Task<ResourcesData> GetResourcesData()
    {
        var cpuUsageData = await Services.GetService<ICpuService>().GetCpuUsageData();

        var memoryData = await Services.GetService<IMemoryService>().GetMemoryData();

        return new ResourcesData { CpuUsageData = cpuUsageData, MemoryData = memoryData };
    }
}
```

Basically, communication is performed via internally developed messaging and both process #1 and process #2 may have access to the results of async operation.

The question is "is it possible to initiate a request to ICpuService.GetCpuUsageData on the process #1 and continue execution on the process #2? i.e. is it possible to break somehow the method to the state machine like async/await does so that the continuation can be resumed on a different process and even on a different server?"

Comment: You want to write code in Process A and inject it to run asynchronously in Process B?  Unless you write yourself some very weird LINQ-ish thing (where you marshal an expression over to the other process and then convert the expression into code on the other side), your aren't going to get what you describe.  The typical way to do this is have Process B expose an RPC-ish API (WCF, REST, DCOM, whatever) and have process A call into that API (which it can do asynchronously).

Comment: Actually both processes have the same codebase, so theoretically all we have to do is serialize/deserialize the data and state machine and make another call to state machine to resume execution on another processes.

Comment: No, this isn't how `async`/`await` are designed. What you're describing sounds more like it needs a proper message bus or something like that doing the communication side and farming out responses to listeners.

Comment: And it's not really the continuation that's the problem - it's where you get a `Task` from that represents the *ongoing work* that `await` is going to wait for completion. If you have a method returning a `Task`, there's no way to copy/pass that `Task` to another process. Sure, you can do some kind of proxying between processes but the processes have to *know about this proxying mechanism and by specifically written to work with it*.

Comment: Interprocess communication is provided by system APIs. For example on windows you have these: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ipc/interprocess-communications but .NET doesn't provide it. async/await abstracts over threads, which can't simply be sent to another process. You can only send data. If you want it to be platform independent and/or between multiple machines you need to use network.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Let me clarify why I'm asking the question regarding async/await continuation and not about interprocess communication. The idea is to implement Fire and Forget architecture while preserving the linear style of code like it is shown in the code above. As you remember async/await solved this problem with regards to simple Begin/End or TPL continuations API

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, async/await already breaks the method apart to various different methods joined in a state machine. And theoretically each of those methods can be called, the issue is to pass the data. Actually, after starting the async operation the current method execution ends and the continuation is simply called in Thread Pool thread, so, once again, theoretically, this can be done on another process as well.

Comment: @ChrisRollins, in fact, as I described in the question we already have internal messaging implemented on the background which allows both processes access the result of the async operation. Moreover, currently, our code is doing Begin/End callbacks and If there was a way to call the continuation of async operation on another process this would allow us to preserve the linear coding like it is shown in the question.

Comment: Yes, anything is *possible*. Just start with the Roslyn compiler and invest as much time again as they did in making `async`/`await` work but with this new magic interprocess communication mechanism in the middle. The point is `async`/`await` as *currently implemented* in C# just plain isn't going to work the way you want it do.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks for your comments, and yes we're not going to invest in building our own compiler or runtime. I was hoping that there was still some workaround because it seemed that the only thing that was missing was capturing the state machine, restoring it on the other process and calling the next method.

Comment: Perhaps something to explore would be to design your own TaskScheduler (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=netframework-4.7.1) which you could use with your interprocess messaging system. In this case you'd be doing all the threading stuff yourself as implementation details of your TaskScheduler. Tasks can be run on a custom TaskScheduler. It might be possible to get async/await to work with this solution but idk this is pretty exotic territory.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible but you'll have to solve couple of major problems apart of workload distribution problems (like load balancing, failure tolerance, etc.). First you'll need to customize the async/await state machine generation possibly with Roslyn in the way similar the Roslyn [does it](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/e6a3ec3348ccdf25083d43502bf42519429148f2/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Lowering/AsyncRewriter/AsyncRewriter.cs) but with necessary modifications and build-in this custom code generation into general build pipeline. Second problem related directly to the changes you'll need to introduce in the "distributed" state machine. In particular there should be serialization/deserialization mechanism which would be able to get the entire state of the state machine instance (including custom variables) and send it on wire or get it from there to restore the state (the state should be synchronized for all instances of a state machine so that continuations can work with the same values of local variables). Obviously the serialization and deserialization should be part of code generation as it will have to deal with local variables. Here is the place where some pitfalls can be encountered since serialization typically has some limitations like non-public members serialization, etc and you will unlikely want to limit usage of local variables inside the async methods by serializable types only. And at last you'll need to generate the distributed communication logic inside the state machine (possibly in the `MoveNext` method). But again there are pitfalls: as communication mainly implies I/O operations you'll likely want to use native async/await mechanism for efficiency which means that the distributed async/await should be distinguished somehow from the native one during the code generation.

Summing this up I'd say that it's possible to implement (with significant effort) but not very practical as async/await was designed with focus on I/O bound operations where it is the most efficient. However distributed I/O load (unlike distributed CPU load) is rather exotic thing due to the nature of I/O operations which scalability mainly rely on the communication channels bandwidth (network, devices) and not so dependent on number of computational units (nodes, CPUs, cores, etc).

Answer (score 0):

For this question:
"is it possible to break somehow the method to the state machine like async/await does so that the continuation can be resumed on a different process and even on a different server?""

You may want to use Threading.Mutex. You can name a Mutex so you can share this Mutex with other processes. Task will not work for this scenario but the effect is similar.
So,
 App Instance1 Thread 1-> MethodA (Acquire the mutex) do the part that matters matters and release the Mutex
 App Instance1 Thread 2 -> MethodB Is Waiting for Mutex to be released and if it is the first to get the release, it will acquire the Mutex and continue what it needs to do
 App Instance2 Thread -> MethodB Is Waiting for Mutex to be released and if it is the first to get the release, it will acquire the Mutex and continue what it needs to do

For inter machines, things get complicated.

Comment: That's not exactly the issue. The issue is that the code should remain exactly as it is shown. To make it happen we need to make it so continuation may resume on another process/machine.